# Why my metrics is displayed within multiple scrapes?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, spring-micrometer

I have got a simple Kotlin + Spring Boot web application and I'm trying to measure the duration time of operation.

Here is the code of my micrometer timer metrics:

```kotlin
    fun recordOrderCreateDuration(duration: Long) {
        Timer
            .builder("my.custom.metrics")
            .tag("application", "order-manager")
            .tag("document", "order")
            .register(meterRegistry)
            .record(duration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
```

I've configured prometheus to scrape interval to 15 seconds:

```json
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'order_monitoring'
    scrape_interval: 15s
```

I need to see a visualization of my operation duration within a single scrape.
If I create query within scrape time then I get nothing for some reason...

```
increase(provisioning_document_duration_seconds_max[15s])
```

If I use some bigger interval, like

```
increase(provisioning_document_duration_seconds_max[1m])
```

then I get the metrics, but due to a minute interval it prolongates to scrapes within certain minute. So visualization of my metrics can contain 1, 2, 3 or 4 15s scrape points (see it on screenshot below)

[image]

What am I doing wrong with that query?

Answer (score 0):

I believe for `increase()` to work properly it needs at least two values within provided range-vector. So minimum range specified could be `30s` for you case, and then you shouldn't have any overlapping. (Basically `provisioning_document_duration_seconds_max - provisioning_document_duration_seconds_max offset 15s`)

On the other hand, it seems like you're looking not for the `increase()` by for the `rate()`. It calculates the per-second average rate of increase of the time series, and it's basically independent of `rate_interval`.

```
rate(provisioning_document_duration_seconds_max[$__rate_interval])
```